# Get rid of duplicate lines in try/catch statement

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a few repeated lines as a result of trying to implement logging. Is there anyway to locate all of these repeated lines using Eclipse's search function?

An example of the duplicate line is shown below.

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception: "+e.getMessage(),e);
        logger.error("Exception: "+e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

I would like to get rid of one of those lines. These cases happen in multiple sections of the code base.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're pretty much on your own on this one. I don't think eclipse can help you too much here

Comment: Can you just go through all `catch` instances?

Comment: Unfortunately,there's around 10,000 of them, so while doable, I'd like to find another solution.

Comment: I'd use something to read my files, I'd write my own program to do that but here is an online tool that claims to do that:  http://textmechanic.com/Remove-Duplicate-Lines.html this is not my tool, just googled "remove duplicated lines tool" I cannot guarantee that it works or that it has viruses :| or inject ads to your code

Comment: I think, with 10,000, you're really looking at writing a program for the purpose.  If eclipse HAD a feature to 'help' do this, I'd likely disable it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regex search and replace on the whole project, if the duplicated lines are consecutive.

As http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html mentions, the regex you could use is:

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

And the replacement would be `\1`

In order to avoid removing lines not related to logging, you can further work on the regular expression. For example, `.*logger.*` would help in only including lines that contain `logger`.

```
^(.*logger.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could search in all your `files` the whole string.-

```
logger.error("Exception: "+e.getMessage(),e);
```

An quick shortcut is copy&paste the line and then do

```
Search => Text => Project
```

But you will have to manually delete the desired results anyway.

Comment: Something tells me, that not all of the log lines are the same, if they are then this works yeah

Comment: Yeah indeed, given the sample snippet it's worthy to give it a try, though.